# Can I register multiple *.tlb files at once in Inno Setup?

Tags: registry, inno-setup, tlb

When I try to register all the *.tlb files using a wildcard:

```
RegisterTypeLibrary(Is64BitInstallMode, ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\TLB\*.tlb');
```

I get the runtime error 0x80029C4A.

Does it mean that I have to register all the files one by one? Is there a way to register a folder?

Comment: Does it work if you only try to register a single TLB?  It's very possible that the RegisterTypeLibrary doesn't accept wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a wildcard for registering the .tlb file. See the [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_registertypelibrary):

> Prototype: procedure RegisterTypeLibrary(const Is64Bit: Boolean; const
>   Filename: String);

e.g. **RegisterTypeLibrary(Is64BitInstallMode, ExpandConstant('{sys}\stdole2.tlb'));**

Also check the correct platform: **Is64BitInstallMode()** has nothing with .tlb  bitness (you can register 32 bit .tlb on 64 bit system without any problem.

The exception is shown if you try to register library for incorrect platform, which might be your problem.

- Extra tip: try to run the installer as *Administrator*, usually the libraries have to be registered in admin mode.

Comment: For individual .tlb files it works. I do have the 64-bit platform. 
You mean running the administrative install mode? Isn't it set by default?